# Connman without any user interaction

Tags: connection, wifi, agent, connman

I'm trying to use Connman to manage the WiFi connection of my embedded system because it handles automagically any type of protection.

In interactive mode it's very simple:

1. connmanctl
2. agent on
3. scan wifi
4. services
5. connect
6. enter password if requested

On my system, the user enters the WiFi credentials (SSID, password) using a remote (web) application. Then I would use this information to setup connman using a script.

The goal is to avoid the user to select which type of protection is going to setup. I mean, most users just enter SSID/password but they don't know if it is a WPA-PSK or WEP connection.

I'm reading throught the documentation, but I'm not sure which is the correct approach:

- a config file: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/connman/connman.git/tree/doc/config-format.txt

but as far as I understand I need to specify the type of the security:

> Security: The security type of the network. Possible values are 'psk' 
>   (WPA/WPA2 PSK), 'ieee8021x' (WPA EAP), 'none' and 'wep'. When not set,
>   the  default value is 'ieee8021x' if an EAP type is configured, 'psk'
>   if a  passphrase is present and 'none' otherwise.

It seems 'wep' is not handled if the field is omitted.

- dbus-api: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/connman/connman.git/tree/doc/manager-api.txt

Here I understand it needs an 'agent' to feed the passphrase, thus I'm afraid I cannot send it programmatically.

Do you have any recommendation about?

Comment: I guess connman has for each session a directory in /var/lib/connman/. So we have to connect manually to a new wifi, create a session and then connman connects to saved wifi automatically.
But I am not sure - just guessing when observing the behavior.